# How to retrieve encrypted AWS secret manager password for database in AWS EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have database password stored in secret manager of AWS and I need to encrypt that using KMS and use that password to connect with database after decrypting in EC2.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I included some Error handling.
Try This one:

```
import boto3
import base64
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def get_secret():
    secret_name = "db_password"
    region_name = "us-east-1"

    # Create a Secrets Manager client
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )

    # In this sample we only handle the specific exceptions for the 'GetSecretValue' API.
    # See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    # We rethrow the exception by default.

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            # Secrets Manager can't decrypt the protected secret text using the provided KMS key.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            # An error occurred on the server side.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            # You provided an invalid value for a parameter.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            # You provided a parameter value that is not valid for the current state of the resource.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            # We can't find the resource that you asked for.
            # Deal with the exception here, and/or rethrow at your discretion.
            raise e
    else:
        # Decrypts secret using the associated KMS CMK.
        # Depending on whether the secret is a string or binary, one of these fields will be populated.
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            decoded_binary_secret = base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
            

    return secret
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write your own logic for that is your programming or scripting language of choice.

Make sure the following is in place:

- The key policy for the KMS key used to encrypt the secret has a statement that allows the account to use the key to decrypt.
- The EC2 instance profile should have permission for `kms:Decrypt` (for the kms key) and `secretsmanager:GetSecretValue` (for the secret).
- write the logic.

For example, from the boto3 docs (python)

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def get_secret():
    secret_name = "MySecretName"
    region_name = "us-west-2"

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name,
    )

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            print("The requested secret " + secret_name + " was not found")
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            print("The request was invalid due to:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            print("The request had invalid params:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailure':
            print("The requested secret can't be decrypted using the provided KMS key:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceError':
            print("An error occurred on service side:", e)
    else:
        # Secrets Manager decrypts the secret value using the associated KMS CMK
        # Depending on whether the secret was a string or binary, only one of these fields will be populated
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            text_secret_data = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            binary_secret_data = get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary']

        # Your code goes here.
```

That should allow you to use the credentials in your python script. Of course any language can be used.